# Detecting mouse move end event in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I need to detect when mouse over mapbox gl js ends movement in order to make a request to the server only when mouse has stopped the movement but it doesn't exist a "mouseStop" event or anything similar in [Mapbox GL JS Api reference](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#events-interaction)

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How would you define "mouse has stopped the movement" event?

Comment: Mouse movement (or, reciprocally, stopping) events get triggered a bazillion times during interaction - you really don't want to use either as request hooks. Rather, each *mousemove* starts/restarts a timeout (so that, while the mouse is moving, it never actually times out) which only triggers a request after no movement has been registered for the timeout duration.

Comment: @TomazicM I mean when mouse stops moving over the map, imagine an "mousemoveends" triggered just after mouse stops move.

Comment: @geozelot Do you have an example that implements this idea?

Comment: Even if/when you implement the solution that @geozelot proposed and is the only sensible one, you'll have to decide what "mouse stops moving" means for you, meaning how much time after the last detected mouse move has to pass to consider it as "mouse has stopped moving" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that works for me along the lines of @geozelot's comments and based on 2on solution of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646825/how-to-detect-when-mouse-has-stopped implemented in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbiewxyz/dNAty/)

I've made this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ToniBCN/1khpe64s/2/) I've decided that timer was equal to 150ms, I think it is enough to detect when "mouse stops" @TomazicM you could try it.

Relevant code:

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
  center: [2.175, 41.40],
  zoom: 12
});

let timer;

function mouseStopped(){

    document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = "Mouse stopped";
    console.log("Mouse stopped");

}

map.on("mousemove", function (e) {

  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(mouseStopped,150);
  
  document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = `${e.lngLat.lng}, ${e.lngLat.lat}`;

});
```

Comment: Added relevant code, thank you @TomazicM